# How to do bulk update in sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a model

```
class Foo(...):
   foo = Column...
   bar = Column...
```

I have a list of pairs t `(foo, bar`) which indicates that for the `Foo` where foo equals t[0] new value of `bar` equals t[1]

How can update many rows in one transaction?

I see `session.bulk_update_mapping`, but from the docs it's not clear to me where to provide arguments for the `where` cause.

Comment: What `where` clause? Is `session.add()` not sufficient? If you just need a bulk, simple insert at fastest speed why involve the ORM? The ORM will be happy to pick up data directly loaded into the database provided it conforms to the model.

Answer (score 3):

[I’m inserting 400,000 rows with the ORM and it’s really slow! - Performance — SQLAlchemy 1.1 Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow) (the 4th in Google on "sqlalchemy bulk update") suggests that ORM is not intended for these - as well as possible ways to go:

> ORMs are basically not intended for high-performance bulk inserts -
>   this is the whole reason SQLAlchemy offers the Core in addition to the
>   ORM as a first-class component.
>
> For the use case of fast bulk inserts, the SQL generation and
>   execution system that the ORM builds on top of is part of the Core.
>   Using this system directly, we can produce an INSERT that is
>   competitive with using the raw database API directly.
>
> Alternatively, the SQLAlchemy ORM offers the Bulk Operations suite of
>   methods, which provide hooks into subsections of the unit of work
>   process in order to emit Core-level INSERT and UPDATE constructs with
>   a small degree of ORM-based automation.